# Ubuntu 18.04 stuck on splash screen after upgrade from 16.04

Tags: boot, nvidia, 18.04

I know this is a common question but before flagging it as a duplicate,please allow me to explain. I encountered this problem in 16.04 as well but it was fixed by changing the boot settings to `nouveau.modeset=0` and then installing the drivers.

However,after the upgrade, I have not been able to boot into Ubuntu normally. I can boot into Ubuntu if I opt for the "recovery mode" option and then switch to "normal boot" after I get to the list of options that the initial boot sequence of the recovery mode has to offer. It should mean that my system is quite capable of booting into normal startup.

What I do not understand is why is it getting stuck on the splash screen if I try to boot it directly from the GRUB? I understand it revolves around my nvidia card and its drivers but I cannot figure out the source of this problem. Also, I am quite new to Linux so I am still learning. I would really like a explanation and a solution to this problem. Thank you.